# Prettyphoto thumbnail margins - How to adjust?

Tags: prettyphoto

Can anyone help me with adjusting (specifically, increasing) margins around PrettyPhoto thumbnails?

http://www.element118.com/codetesting/118_NewSite_Test/work.html

I've fiddled with the CSS and JS files but nothing I've tried so far changes anything. I did try the forums at No Margin for Error but there's been no reply to my post for weeks and the forums there seem to be full of spam now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust this class in prettyPhoto.css `div.pp_default .pp_gallery ul li a`

```
div.pp_default .pp_gallery ul li a
{
   margin-top:2px
}
```